# Decay constant Question in A level AQA physics

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Mark scheme
[image]
I don't understand 2.7. I have attatched the relevant part of the question and markscheme and also the links to full versions below.

Apparantely you use the decay constant in 2.5 to find specific points on the graph. (The starting point is just half the original graph. For other points, u can say y1 = 34e^(-4.5*10^-3 * t) I don't see how that is valid. When you alter the experiment shouldn't the decay constant also change?
Full paper: https://mmerevise.co.uk/app/uploads/2021/09/AQA-A-Level-Physics-Paper-3A-QP.pdf
Mark scheme: https://mmerevise.co.uk/app/uploads/2021/09/AQA-A-Level-Physics-Paper-3A-MS.pdf

Comment: $sin(30^\circ)=0.5$. So make the assumption that with half the pressure the flow rate is going to halve. *When you alter the experiment shouldn't the decay constant also change?* Imagine the original apparatus being used but with smaller values of $y$, the decay constant does not change.

Comment: @Farcher I see. One thing I don’t understand. When you tilt the tube the acceleration along the plane due to gravity decreases. Ur not just changing the height. But also the acceleration. So, how can u still make that assumption

Comment: The problem is to do with the rate of flow through a horizontal tube which is assumed depend on the pressure difference between the ends of the horizontal tube.